# How can I change element of numpy array manually?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Following is my numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
arrc=arr
arrc[arr<3]=3
```

When I run

```
>>> arrc
output : array([3,3,3,4,5])

>>> arr
output : array([3,3,3,4,5])
```

I expected changing arrc does not affect arr. However, both array is changing. In my actual code I am changing arrc multiple times so I observe error if arrc have influence to arr. Is there any good way to fix this?

Comment: You might mean `arrc = arr.copy()`. Otherwise `arrc` and `arr` are references to the same array.

Comment: `arrc=arr` - just assigns the same object to the new variable name.  It does not make a copy.  This isn't just a `numpy` thing; it's basic Python.  But with `numpy` you also have to know when something is a `view` instead of a `copy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `.copy()` when you copy array values. Otherwise, it is the same reference you update with both variables.

Use:

```
arrc = arr.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, just index the element and set the value.

```
a[1,2] = "some value"
```

Comment: I have to use conditions because in my actual code the array has more than 20,000 index and they are in random order.